# How can I ask this question in Blender Stack Exchange, without it being closed due to being opinion based?

Tags: discussion

The following is the question I recently posted on Blender Stack Exchange, but it was closed because it was opinion based:

[What is the standard technical workflow for high quality short films?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/281560/)

What does a standard technical workflow for a high-quality animated short film look like in detail, from inception to finished product? Technical in the sense of modeling, textures, rigging, compositing, animation etc.

How can I phrase this question more objectively without straying too far from my actual question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to add to Quellenform's answer, this question is much too broad for this site. Ask yourself, what would an acceptable or satisfying answer to your question look like?

Would a full description of a lengthy studio workflow, complete with employees roles, software used, standard practices be enough? Should it include step by step procedures or corner cases? That alone would probably be enough material to write a small book. That is way too long for our Q&A format, not to mention that it might well require including "trade secrets" most would not be willing to disclose publicly.

It is also something that is not universal across studios using similar software suites, let alone some global industry standard across so many different possible workflows. I don't even think it would be the exact same across different projects inside the same studio, as things adapt to particular project requirements.

To potentially make your questions on topic here I think it should be broken down into smaller issues, or focus on the single aspect you are having difficulties with.

From your post it seems to concern mostly performance or optimizations, so perhaps focus on those points alone.

Be sure to identify what are the bottlenecks of your scene, and search existing answers for solutions we already described.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a usual forum, but a Q&A platform. Therefore the focus is to solve specific individual problems.

[How do I ask a good question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

[Guidelines for great subjective questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)

However, your question is not focused enough and there are just too many answers to it because everyone looks at this issue differently.

Therefore, this is a question for search engines, books, studies, courses and there is a lot of technical knowledge and experience behind it.

It is therefore less suitable for this platform in this form, since no generally valid and comprehensive answer can be given.

You could do some research on the net and try out a workflow. If you have a specific problem that can be answered clearly, then you can ask this question here and I am sure that then the question will not be closed and there will be an answer.

If you want to get opinions, there are still the many Blender forums on the net, which are more suitable for discussions.